# Is there a way to import python module into groovy language in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a python library containing common functionalities such as createFile, createFolder, checkIfFolderExists etc., Is it possible to import this library functions into Jenkins pipeline script (Groovy)?

Comment: The examples you used there are allready there in groovy (and python). Yet you can just call your python script using that library. Other than that: jython

Comment: @cfrick I am trying to make a library of reusable functions in python, so I wanted this to be accessed in Jenkins Pipeline script.

Comment: but all of those functions exist natively in jenkins - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/
You would need a groovy library that invokes python scripts to do what your asking